# how do I create an emerging panel that will overlap the content, and not shift it down?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am studying jetpack compose and at the moment I am writing another application for practice using a design-layout.

In this desiged-layout when you click on the `FilledTonalButton` a panel appears from below that overlaps the content located under some "component with our button". I mean, this panel is "on top of it". As in the following picture.
[design-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO2mY.png)

Unfortunately I don't understand how I can do this.

There were no similar codelabs in the courses from Google, I also could not find something similar on the Internet, ChatGPT 3.5 did not help either. This is not the first time I see this technique. Perhaps a custom view is being created for this?

I tried to use `BottomSheet` and `Scaffold`, but something remotely similar didn't work out.

Comment: what do you want to do? clarify it

Comment: @ChiragThummar, I would like the surface to appear on top of the content when the button is clicked, as BottomSheet does.

Comment: You can use Dialog for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dialog` for showing content like that

In the below example I have given code for `Dialog` and how to use them in screen.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Dialog
import com.example.jetpackcomposeplayground.ui.theme.JetpackComposePlayGroundTheme

@Composable
fun FileInfoDialog(
    setShowDialog: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    setValue: (String) -> Unit,
    onClose: () -> Unit
) {

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { setShowDialog(false) }) {
        Surface(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp), color = Color.White
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .padding(20.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Info",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(42.dp)
                        .background(color = Color.Red)
                        .clickable {
                            onClose()
                        },
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Close", color = Color.White)
                }

            }

        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun Sample() {
    val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (showDialog.value) {

        FileInfoDialog(
            setShowDialog = {
                showDialog.value = it
            },
            setValue = {},
        ) {
            showDialog.value = false
        }
    }



    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(42.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Gray)
                .clickable {
                   showDialog.value = true
                },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = "Open Dialog", color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}
```